# Using $this when not in object context, when call method of object in array in foreach

Tags: php

i'm PHP programer

i have Class ActionDTO in ActionDTO.php

```
class ActionDTO {
    private $totalCount;

    public function getTotalCount(){
        return $this->totalCount;
    }

    public function setTotalCount($totalCount){
        $this->totalCount = $totalCount;
    }
}
```

and Main.php

```
$a = new ActionDTO();         // create new instance
$b = [$a];                    // add it to array
foreach($b as $value){        // loop all item in $b
    print_r($value);          // show info of object ActionDTO, it right!
    echo $value::getTotalCount(); // **
}
```

but, at **, i give

```
PHP Fatal error:  Using $this when not in object context in /path/to/ActionDTO.php on line 35
```

i don't known, why it error!

Comment: `$value->getTotalCount();` using `::` calls the function static

Comment: try echo $value->getTotalCount()

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the function with `::` but it is not static method. So use the code below

```
$a = new ActionDTO();         // create new instance
$b = [$a];                    // add it to array
foreach($b as $value){        // loop all item in $b
    print_r($value);          // show info of object ActionDTO, it right!
    echo $value->getTotalCount(); // **
}
```

Hope this helps you